# Cryptopals 1.2 in Nim: XOR returns an unexpected value

Tags: cryptography, nim-lang

I thought doing the Cryptopals exercises in Nim would be a nice way to learn the language. On [set 1 exercise 2](https://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/2), I'm getting an unexpected result on the `xor` part. The exercise:

> If your function works properly, then when you feed it the string:
>
> `1c0111001f010100061a024b53535009181c`
>
> ... after hex decoding, and when XOR'd against:
>
> `686974207468652062756c6c277320657965`
>
> ... should produce:
>
> `746865206b696420646f6e277420706c6179`

The [Python solution](https://github.com/ricpacca/cryptopals/blob/master/S1C02.py) is very obvious. I've been doing the exercises in Node.js and it's a no-brainer as well.

My solution in Nim:

```
import strutils as strutils

var a, b = 0

a = toU16(strutils.parseHexInt("1c0111001f010100061a024b53535009181c"))
b = toU16(strutils.parseHexInt("686974207468652062756c6c277320657965"))

let result = toHex(a xor b)
```

The outputs are:

- a: 165317428619319324
- b: 7812662828999211365
- (a xor b): 7937440550937715065
- hex(a xor b): 0000000000006179

This is not at all what I'd expect. Am I parsing hexadecimals and/or binary incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`parseHexStr`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/strutils.html#parseHexStr,string) on both the input and the input for the second parameter of the XOR operation. Then you can XOR each byte separately and store the result in a new array.

Nim integers are the same size as Nim pointers. You're parsing two large byte arrays in hexadecimals, while the result is a smaller integer. Or, to be more specific, the input values and result you're getting are calculated *modulus two to the power 64* as you're probably working on a 64 bit CPU.

Comment: I was able to at least get a proper `xor`ed string in the end, although it's not what's expected. Perhaps it's best to learn Nim some other way. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @FilipeCatraia You've just been pampered by Python, which is able to use unlimited precision integers by default :) Not many language do (while this would clearly be a boon, especially from a testing / security perspective, where handling values that silently overflow is a complete nightmare).

Comment: yes, higher-level languages in general make one too comfortable. Nim has been a real eye-opener.